# How can I make a data table work properly using Zurb Ink

Tags: css, html-table, zurb-ink

I am using Ink to try and create an order confirmation e-mail from an ecommerce store. If I have a table that shows item info or any sort of data I layout, the last column is crunched to one character width when resizing to small. Example code in a 6-column cell is attached for code as well as the output screenshot.

Any ideas how I can fix this?

[image: Screenshot]

```
                      <table class="six columns">
                    <tr>
                      <td>
                          <table width="100%">
                            <tr>
                                <td>Subtotal</td>
                                <td>$60.00</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Shipping & Handling</td>
                                <td>$11.91</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><strong>Grand Total</strong></td>
                                <td><strong>$71.91</strong></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                      </td>
                      <td class="expander"></td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
```

Comment: I have the same problem, i think it needs to be wrapped in a #content or sometihng, with custom css to try and overide INK CSS 
```@media only screen and (max-width: 600px)
table[class=body] table.column td, table[class=body] table.columns td {
 width: 100%!important; 
}```

Answer (score 0):

A Ink `sub-grid` would be useful here.

**HTML**

```
<table class="body">
<tr>
  <td class="center" align="center" valign="top">
    <div class="c1">
      <table class="row">
        <tr>
          <td class="wrapper">
            <table class="twelve columns">
              <tr>
                <td class="ten sub-columns">Subtotal</td>

                <td class="two sub-columns last">$10</td>

                <td class="expander"></td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>

      <table class="row">
        <tr>
          <td class="wrapper">
            <table class="twelve columns">
              <tr>
                <td class="ten sub-columns">S&amp;H</td>

                <td class="two sub-columns last">$2</td>

                <td class="expander"></td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>

      <table class="row">
        <tr>
          <td class="wrapper">
            <table class="twelve columns">
              <tr>
                <td class="ten sub-columns">Total</td>

                <td class="two sub-columns last">$12</td>

                <td class="expander"></td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

Here's the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/brettdewoody/qof0o78h/).

Answer (score 0):

I think Ink is only for creating responsive e-mail layouts. If you want something more, you can use standard HTML. So `<table>` with `<tr>`, `<td>` and `<th>`.